# OCZ SSD drive reviews are very polarized, whereas Corsair and Sandisk reviews are mostly great - What's up with OCZ?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

Looking at Amazon reviews for OCZ Agility and Vertex SSD drives, I often see an equal number of great reviews and lousy reviews.  People either seem to love them and have no issues or have tons of problems.  Reviews for Corsair and Sandisk drives generally seem good to great.

What's the story with OCZ?

Comment: I find OCZ to be one of the most disturbing companies i have experience dealing with. Try to update their Firmware to see. Explore their website past the initial links for instructions on firmware updates and you will find the most immature support structure and documentation. For mac, as an example, you have to setup a linux cd but they recommend for some major issues (drive fail after sleep) to update to 1.5 but in other parts of the forum they say the linux tools will not provide 1.5 you are left with taking your drive from your osx machine to someones windows machine and doing the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been reported cases of fake reviews written by OCZ employees, see http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/02/28/ocz_fake_reviews/. These might have been written to compensate the rather negative real reviews from customers and could explain the inconsistent ratings.

Comment: No, this only tells that some of the positive reviews are fake, the article does not mention that the bad reviews are real, they could have come from a competitor. Is is common practise to fake reviews, OCZ is not the only one, their fault is that they were caught.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch What's really their fault is making drives which are bad enough that they need to cheat and write fake reviews. Not that they were caught making those reviews.

Comment: I don't believe the OCZ reviews are all fake. For example, I have used three OCZ drives and I have liked all of them. My current Vertex is running great.